# How can newly created files and directories inherit permission from their parent directory?

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I want to set up a folder such that anything created within it (directories, files) inherit default permissions 777. Can we set a umask for a particular directory to achieve this?

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to use 777.

Comment: you *can't* have files created by default with execute permission - no umask setting allows it

Comment: `umask` is not a per-directory setting. It is a per-process setting, and governs only the behavior of that process and its children (unless the child process changes umask).